# How to prove that following sequence is bounded in norm?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in a Hilbert space $H$ and $a$ is an element of $H$, Given that $$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim {\sup}}\ \|x_n -a\| \leq \|x^*-a\| $$ where $x^*$ is some fixed element of $H$. Then how to prove that $\{x_n\}$ is a bounded sequence.

I started with $$\|x_n\| \leq \|x_n-a\|+ \|a\|$$Then unable to solve further. How to make use of given inequality. Can i write $$\|x_n\| \leq \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim {\sup}}\ \|x_n -a\|+ \|a\|$$ Please explain this.

Comment: First, the notation should be $\underset{k \to \infty}{\lim {\sup}}\ \|x_k -a\|$. Now, if you consider $\|x_n\| \leq \|x_n-a\|+ \|a\|$ you can take limits but on both sides of the inequality...

Comment: yes. but i thought if there is a relation between a term of a sequence and limit sup

Comment: You are almost there, just don't do anything illegal: if you take limits take them in both sides of the inequality.

Comment: Then i get $\lim\sup \|x_n\|$ bounded